# handling DirectoryNotFoundException errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I offer up file downloads from my website to users.  When the file exists, it works fine.  But if the file is removed for whatever reason, I get the following error in Visual Studio:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in
mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

and the users just see a JSON string on the website.

I use this offer up a stream:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(
      new FileStream(mediaFile.FilesystemLocation, FileMode.Open));
```

`mediaFile.FilesystemLocation` is simply this:

```
public virtual string FilesystemLocation
{
     get { return Path.Combine(FilesystemRoot, Id + "." + Extension); }
}
```

I tried putting the whole thing in a try/catch block but then it lost all it's references to other classes.

So my question is, how can I handle this code and prevent this error?

Ideally, I'd just like to display a message to the user, "File Not Found, please contact your Administrator" or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: 'putting the whole thing in a try/catch block' should not cause any references to be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.IO.File.Exists` is going to be your friend here.  Before you set `result.Content` call this first.  If the file doesn't exist, the method will return `false` and you can adjust your logic accordingly.

```
var filepath = mediaFile.FilesystemLocation;

if (!File.Exists(filepath))
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(404);
}
else{
   var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

   //just in case file has disappeared / or is locked for open, 
   //wrap in try/catch
   try
   {
       result.Content = new StreamContent(
          new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open));
   }
   catch
   {
       return new HttpResponseMessage(500);           
   }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: but you'll still need to try/catch around result.Content = ..., as you can still have the file go away between the check for it's existence and opening it.

Comment: With try/catch blocks, how can I prevent the code inside the try/catch block from losing references? For example, when I put the code in a try/catch block it can no longer find 'mediaFile.FilesystemLocation'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `losing references`, but in this example I've copied `mediaFile.FileSystemLocaltion` to a locally scoped variable that can be read inside the try/catch.  Additionally, `result` was created outside of the try/catch so it be read both inside the try/catch and out.